# a question regarding NTFS filter driver

Tags: windows, drivers, kernel

does anyone have an article regarding writing filter drivers for the NTFS ?

another question - when im writing a filter driver for NTFS, can I just pass down my IRP using IoSkipCurrentIrpStackLocation(...) and IoCallDriver(...) when I get MajorFunction I dont want to take care of
 ?
ofcourse the call to IoCallDriver will include a pointer to the next device in the list

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You *really* don't want to do this using WDM. Seriously. This is a very common scenario, and there is a framework specifically for this purpose - check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms793580.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/erick/archive/2006/03/27/562257.aspx